# add input to numpy 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I have a pandas DataFrame that i transform to numpy array like this

```
  training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

  X_train = []
  for i in range(60, 1258):
      X_train.append(training_set[i-60:i, 0])
      y_train.append(training_set[i, 0])

  X1_train = np.array(X1_train)
```

> X1_train.shape = (1198, 60)

after a create a 3d array

```
X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1] , 1))
```

> X2_train.shape = (1198,0)

now when a try to add a new input `x2_train.shape[0], x2_train.shape[1]` in my array and I am blocked

I tried several things like this

```
X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, ([X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1], X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1]] , 1))

X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1] , 1))
```

i have this error when a run my code

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 257, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 62, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 42, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

and the [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is not very clear

Comment: How did you try to add the new input?

Comment: `X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, ([X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1], X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1]] , 1)) 

X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1] , 1))

X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, ([X1_train.shape[0], [X2_train.shape[0], [X1_train.shape[1] , [X2_train.shape[1] , 1))`

Comment: What are the errors that you get? And what is the shape of `X2_train`?

Comment: X2_train.shape is the same of X1_train and my error is


`  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 257, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 62, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 42, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your response is good but you are not forgetting to reshape your array

you can remove this

```
  X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1] , 1))

 X2_train = np.reshape(X2_train, (X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1] , 1))


new_train  = np.dstack((X1_train, X2_train))
```

and just write your code like this

```
new_train  = np.dstack((X1_train, X2_train))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is replace the line

```
X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1] , 1))
```

and replace by

```
X1_train = np.reshape(X1_train, (X1_train.shape[0], X1_train.shape[1] , 1))

 X2_train = np.reshape(X2_train, (X2_train.shape[0], X2_train.shape[1] , 1))


new_train  = np.dstack((X1_train, X2_train))
```

this a the 2 dimension to 3d array

> new_train.shape = (1198, 60, 2)